# Finding primary takes long time JAVA

Tags: java, loops

I don't know if I am using this code properly -> main. It is extremely slow. It is DDS algorithm.
It is implementation of DSA: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm

THIS LOOP TAKES MUCH TIME

```
do {
            pTemp = new BigInteger(l, primeCenterie, rand);
            pTemp2 = pTemp.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
            pTemp = pTemp.subtract(pTemp2.remainder(q));
            System.out.println("1 " + i++);
        } while (!pTemp.isProbablePrime(primeCenterie)
                || pTemp.bitLength() != l);
```

I added some printlns and even them are slow.

```
 import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Key {
    int primeCenterie = 20;
    BigInteger q;
    BigInteger p;
    BigInteger g;
    BigInteger y;
    BigInteger x;
    BigInteger k;
    Random rand = new Random();

    Key() {
    }

    public void generateKey() {
        q = new BigInteger(160, primeCenterie, rand);
        p = generateP(q, 512);
        g = generateG(p, q);
        do {
            x = new BigInteger(q.bitCount(), rand);
        } while (x.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != 1 && x.compareTo(q) != -1);
        y = g.modPow(x, p);
    }

    private BigInteger generateP(BigInteger q, int l) {
        if (l % 64 != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("L value is wrong");
        }
        BigInteger pTemp;
        BigInteger pTemp2;
        int i = 0;
        do {
            pTemp = new BigInteger(l, primeCenterie, rand);
            pTemp2 = pTemp.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
            pTemp = pTemp.subtract(pTemp2.remainder(q));
            System.out.println("1 " + i++);
        } while (!pTemp.isProbablePrime(primeCenterie)
                || pTemp.bitLength() != l);
        return pTemp;
    }

    private BigInteger generateG(BigInteger p, BigInteger q) {
        BigInteger aux = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        BigInteger pow = aux.divide(q);
        BigInteger gTemp;
        int i = 0;
        do {
            gTemp = new BigInteger(aux.bitLength(), rand);
            System.out.println("2 " + i++);
        } while (gTemp.compareTo(aux) != -1
                && gTemp.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) != 1);
        return gTemp.modPow(pow, p);
    }

    public BigInteger generateK(BigInteger q) {
        BigInteger tempK;
        int i = 0;
        do {
            tempK = new BigInteger(q.bitLength(), rand);
            System.out.println("3 " + i++);
        } while (tempK.compareTo(q) != -1
                && tempK.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != 1);
        return tempK;
    }

    public BigInteger generateR() {
        k = generateK(q);
        BigInteger r = g.modPow(k, p).mod(q);
        return r;
    }

    public BigInteger generateS(BigInteger r, byte[] data) {
        MessageDigest md;
        BigInteger s = BigInteger.ONE;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            md.update(data);
            BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(md.digest());
            s = (k.modInverse(q).multiply(hash.add(x.multiply(r)))).mod(q);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DSA.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return s;
    }

    boolean verify(byte[] data, BigInteger r, BigInteger s) {
        if (r.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) <= 0 || r.compareTo(q) >= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if (s.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) <= 0 || s.compareTo(q) >= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        MessageDigest md;
        BigInteger v = BigInteger.ZERO;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            md.update(data);
            BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(md.digest());
            BigInteger w = s.modInverse(q);
            BigInteger u1 = hash.multiply(w).mod(q);
            BigInteger u2 = r.multiply(w).mod(q);
            v = ((g.modPow(u1, p).multiply(y.modPow(u2, p))).mod(p)).mod(q);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DSA.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return v.compareTo(r) == 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Key key = new Key();
        key.generateKey();
        byte[] data = "a".getBytes();
        BigInteger r = key.generateR();
        BigInteger s = key.generateS(r, data);
        System.out.println(key.verify(data,r,s)); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A profiler would be best here, but I think your problem is isProbablePrime.  You're passing in 20, which basically means you want a .9999999 certainty.  Try a smaller parameter or use other method for primality testing...

```
isProbablePrime

public boolean isProbablePrime(int certainty)

    Returns true if this BigInteger is probably prime, false if it's definitely composite. If certainty is <= 0, true is returned.

    Parameters:
        certainty - a measure of the uncertainty that the caller is willing to tolerate: if the call returns true the probability that this BigInteger is prime exceeds (1 - 1/2certainty). The execution time of this method is proportional to the value of this parameter. 
    Returns:
        true if this BigInteger is probably prime, false if it's definitely composite.
```

Comment: Really don't know how correct this method. I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Try using primeCenterie=1, just to see if that speeds it up